# Illustrator script: Selecting objects in layer

Tags: object, layer

So I have a script that should select the objects of a layer and deselect it afterwards. (adobe Illustrator)

But for some reason after it deselects, it automaticly selects an object that doesn't appear anywhere in my layers together with the next selected object.

What could this be?

```
myDoc = app.activeDocument;
myLayers = myDoc.layers;

for (var a=0; a<myLayers.length; a++)
{
    //Select objects in layer
    myLayers[a].hasSelectedArtwork = true;

    //Do action here

    //Deselect objects in layer
    myLayers[a].hasSelectedArtwork = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by adding this to the beginning of the loop.

```
 app.activeDocument.selection = null;
```